# C++ Find average of a vector of multi dimensional arrays of complex float

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, complex-numbers, moving-average

I was wondering if there is any way to store multi dimensional arrays in a vector and find average of the arrays. Each of the array contains same dimensions of complex float.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> 
class MyGarden : public LittleGarden<T>
{
public:

    typedef LittleGarden<T> BaseClass;
    typedef typename BaseClass::value_type value_type;

    using BaseClass::Flowers_info;
    using BaseClass::Average;
};

 std::vector<array<T>> Collection;
 Collection.push_back(Flowers_info);  
 Average = std::accumulate(Collection.begin(),Collection.end(), 0)/Collection.size();
```

But I got error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘array<std::complex<float> >’ and ‘std::vector<array<std::complex<float> >, std::allocator<array<std::complex<float> > > >::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)
Average = std::accumulate(Collection.begin(),Collection.end(), 0)/Collection.size();
        ^
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘array<std::complex<float> >’)  
   __init = __init + *__first;
                   ^
note:mismatched types ‘complext<T>’ and ‘int’
```

It is in a .h file and it works when Flowers_info is directly used without going into the vector, but I want to collect about 10 Flowers_info and make average before it is used. Now the vector has same dimensions as Flowers_info, however making average of the multi dimensional arrays of those complex number is quite difficult. I could not solve this by myself, could anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the "average of arrays"? And where is there multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: You need to pass a functor to `std::accumulate` that knows what to do with two `std::array<std::complex<float>>>`. See [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: Also, what is this `array`? `std::array` has two parameters, type and number of elements

Comment: What is the type of Flower_info? As the compiler error indicates, the type of Flower_info does not have the `operator=` and `operator+` defined. The type `array<std::complex<float>>` does not have these operators.